# PDF Invoice Generation in Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am trying to check for new orders in Magento and if they exist, send a PDF invoice to the site admins. Everything is great except for the PDF.

When trying to externally create PDF invoices, all billing information is missing from the rendered PDF. Creating the invoice is fairly straight-forward, but finding the reason for the missing billing information has been impossible for me. Here is what I have learned.

My code for creating the actual PDF invoice is below. This is the same code used in the default `pdfinvoicesAction` to create PDFs for the admin back-end (`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php:459`).

`cron/Invoice.php`

```
<?php
  /* $order is a valid Mage_Sales_Model_Order object */

  $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
  $pdfInvoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice');
  $pdf = $pdfInvoice->getPdf($invoices);

  $pdfFile = $pdf->render();
?>
```

This creates a valid PDF, containing all order information minus billing. Isolating the cause for this, I found that in the following (default) file, order billing information is an empty string - when I retrieve the invoice via the magento back-end this returns a formatted string containing all billing information.

`app/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php:221`

```
    /* Payment */
    $paymentInfo = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())
        ->setIsSecureMode(true)
        ->toPdf();

    // $paymentInfo is an empty string when rendering a PDF externally,
    // and formatted as expected when rendering a PDF via the admin panel

    $payment = explode('{{pdf_row_separator}}', $paymentInfo);
```

So that's whats happening. I have no idea how or why. The real kicker? In my cron job script, if I run the following:

```
die(print_r($order->getPayment()->toArray()));
```

All the payment info is there.

I've asked this in the development forum of the Magento website with no luck. I'm really hoping someone could help shed light on this issue, as I've exhausted my debugging efforts. Thank you so much.

Edit: Just found out that while `Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true)->toHtml()` returns properly formatted HTML. `->toPdf` still returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I hope this helps someone else. Sometimes when you ask a detailed question, it gets you thinking more clearly. It was a very simple solution, with no clear error message indicating what the problem was!

Magento uses two folders for template files `adminhtml` and `frontend`. By default, there is only a .phtml for the payment data helper pdf action on the **back-end**. My script was **running on the front-end**, not finding this file, and outputting an empty string.

So in short, if your PDF invoices in Magento <= 1.6.1 are missing billing information when rendered on the front-end, take this file:

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/paygate/info/pdf.phtml`

Then copy/paste it to:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paygate/info/pdf.phtml` (Or if you prefer, your custom template directory)

In hindsight, I probably should be using the back-end layout for my cron scripts.

Edit: Today I learned about the var/log/system.log file in Magento... (Re-editing for clarity) The /var/log/system.log file was clearly telling me what the problem was, I just failed to read it.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. When stepping through in xdebug, I noticed the PDF wants to load the payment info from this template file: frontend/base/default/template/payment/info/pdf/purchaseorder.phtml which does not exist in default Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Mahdi.Montgomery's solution, but it never worked for me.

My problem is almost the same, but instead of missing billing information, I have missing payment method. But my gut feel is that the root cause is the same - the PDF template of the admin and frontend is different, which is not very intuitive. My gut feel happens to be right.

I saw this link from http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/463492/

> Answering my own question, it is a Magento bug, see
>   http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/{path:viewforum}/viewthread/270256/#t397540
>
> Fix:
>
> In frontend/base/default/template/payment/info , create a folder pdf
>   and copy all the .phtml files into it.

Hope this helps someone.